# How to Handle errors on ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, error-handling, extjs6

I want to be able to catch any error thrown on my screen. So far my  code is this:

```
Ext.application({
    errorHandler:function(err){
        alert(err.msg);
        return true;
    },
    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.ajax.JsonSimlet',
        'Ext.ux.ajax.SimManager'
    ],

    views: [
        'Admin.view.something', 
        'Admin.view.somethingController'
    ],

    name: 'Admin',

    launch : function() {Ext.create('Admin.view.something');
    Ext.Error.notify = false;
    Ext.Error.handle = this.errorHandler;
    }
});
```

The problem is, I have some objects that may be undefined. If I do something like undefined.properties, the error handling doesn't catch it.

I know about functions like "Ext.isDefined()", but for this case I really need to handle all generic errors in the same way.

Comment: Have a look at the Ext.Error.handle function https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.Error.html#static-method-handle

Comment: @And-y I did saw that. I've tried to implement it on my project (as you might see on the code), yet it doesn't work if I do something like data.length (where data is undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.Error.handle` only handles errors raised by `Ext.raise` according to the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.Error.html#static-method-handle).

A solution to handle plain javascript errors is the `error` event on the browsers window.
You can attach an handler with `window.addEventListener('error', function(event) { ... })` to it.

The following code should catch all errors in your project.

```
launch : function() {
    Ext.Error.notify = false;
    Ext.Error.handle = this.errorHandler;
    window.addEventListener('error', this.errorJsHandler);
    Ext.create('Admin.view.something');
},
errorJsHandler: function(err) { // err = ErrorEvent Object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent
        alert(err.message);
        return true;  // prevent the firing of the default event handler
},
```